# How to convert e.Result (that returned by WCF service) to the List <>?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, wcf, web-services

There is a WCF service:

```
    public List<Aktivy> Aktivy()
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var aktivy = from akt in db.Aktivys
                     select aktivy;
        return aktivy.ToList();
    }
```

Also there is a Silverlight client that accesses the WCF service:

```
    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference.ServiceClient webService = new ServiceReference.ServiceClient();
        webService.AktivyCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference.AktivyCompletedEventArgs>(webService_AktivyCompleted);
        webService.AktivyAsync();
    }

    void webService_AktivyCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference.AktivyCompletedEventArgs e)
    {            

    }
```

How to convert e.Result (which features webService_AktivyCompleted) in the `List<Aktivy>` on the client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default when you configure a service reference in Silverlight the collection types are set to deserialise into `ObservableCollection<T>` (which is not a `List<T>`).  If you always want a simple `List<T>` you can modify the configuration of the service reference (right mouse on the service in Solution Explorer) and set collections to be represented as `List<T>`.

However a better approach when dealing with these things is to work with interfaces instead of demanding a specific type.  Modify your code to work with `IList<T>` (a `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>`) instead of `List<T>`, this will work with any of the possible collection types that a service may be configured for.

Since `ObservableCollection<T>` is the most versatile of the available choices you would have to have a good reason why the collection **must** be `List<T>`.  One reason might be because you are sharing code between server and client.

Answer (score 3):

What about to just cast the e.Result to List?

```
var listOfAktivy = (List<Aktivy>)e.Result;
```

Anyway you can view the type of e.Result in watch/quick watch window.

Comment: That probably won't work with all other things being at their defaults.  `e.Result` will not be of type `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on how you have configured you client to generate the collection types in the service reference.

By default the client will generate simple arrays from the definitions in wsdl I believe, but it is possible to configure it to generate List instead (by changing the option Collection type in the advanced tab of the add service reference dialog to System.Collections.Generic.List).

Which ever way you have it I think this will work (but I have not tested it:

```
List<Aktivity> listOfAktivy = new List<Aktivy>((IEnumerable<Aktivity>)e.Result);
```

Comment: That code isn't very efficient, you are asking code duplicate the entire result.  Its much better to configure the service reference corrrectly as you have stated.

Comment: @Anthony, I agree totally.  It was really a response to @Kamarey answer which will not work if the result is not already a list type.  I'll edit to make that more clear.